# Selecting randomly by FIFO

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm not exactly sure how to word this question...

We have parts stored in a "LOGDATA" table like this:
Proj Log | Project | Log  | Serial_NO | Part_Serial | ...
A 100 | A | 100 | SN0001 | 1234567 SN0001
A 101 | A | 101 | SN0002 | 1234567 SN0002
A 102 | A | 102 | SN0003 | 1234567 SN0003
B 103 | B | 103 | SN0004 | 1234567 SN0004
B 104 | B | 104 | SN0005 | 1234567 SN0005
B 105 | B | 105 | SN0006 | 1234567 SN0006
C 106 | C | 106 | SN0007 | 1234567 SN0007
etc...

As one can see, the same part number has multiple receipts across several projects.

In the environment, we have pickers that display available hardware for install in FIFO order by Log Numbers. So as in the table sample above, one would see that all the hardware in project A would be used first, followed by B then C...

The users would like a new algorithm that would randomize the picker while still keeping FIFO order within each project. To clarify:

On the first load the picker may show:
C 106
B 103
A 100
B 104
A 101
C 107

On a second load of the picker, it could show:
B 104
A 100
C 106
B 105
C 107
A 101

I'm not the developer of the environment and as such do not have any SQL to show how they are currently pulling the hardware into the picker. From what I put above and what I've been told, it seems like a simple select from the LOGDATA table with an order by on the log field.

Thanks to those viewing this post. I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: I've read through twice and don't follow what it is you're after here.   :(   Perhaps you could show your existing query and/or expand your example data?

Comment: I agree with _Hart CO_ - I was following up until "The new algorithm should..." where there are too many hidden assumptions (it may make sense to you but not to someone unfamiliar with your situation) . Also, it would help to have one or more examples of correct output. And (since this is an SQL question) table structures (even simplified ones) would help us to frame the answer. Perhaps also clarify if you need a consistent result  (same result every time the query is executed) or if a different (correct) answer each time is acceptable.

Comment: Among other thoughts, how many pickers do you have, and how many projects? Why would the last five be relevant? Should each user only see logs from projects other than the one *they* last saw, or that anyone saw? Just randomising seems a lot simpler, particularly with a larger number of projects. What is the downside of that? Oh, and do the FIFOs have timestamps associated, so you could combine all the projects into a single virtual queue to pick the first value? (I guess not, but worth checking the obvious sometimes....)

Comment: So I reread the question again - and confused myself. Not really sure what I was thinking, Lol. Anyway, it has been edited with a table sample and sample outputs to better clarify the need. Thanks to all who view this.